# Is it possible to receive push notifications when Safari is closed for web

Tags: push-notification, safari, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications, service-worker

I have created a web application that requires background notifications when a browser is closed. I have implemented firebase messaging with service workers and the implementation works for seemingly all browsers except Safari.

For Safari, it will receive the notification when the tab is open, but as soon as the tab or browser is closed, it fails to receive the notification.

My understanding is that service workers are immediately killed when the tab is closed.

I read about periodic sync in order to get it to work on Safari and have implemented it as follows within my service worker:

```
// Function to show notification during periodic sync - SAFARI ONLY
const showNotificationDuringSync = async (payload) => {
  try {
    console.log('Received background message during sync: ', payload);

    const notificationTitle = payload.data.title;
    const notificationOptions = {
      body: payload.data.body,
      icon: payload.data.icon,
      data: {
        // Add the URL to the notification data
        url: payload.data.url,
      }
    };

    await self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle, notificationOptions);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error showing notification during sync:', error);
  }
};

// Check if the browser is Safari
const isSafari = /^((?!chrome|android).)*safari/i.test(navigator.userAgent);

if (isSafari) {
  console.log('Running in Safari, setting up periodic sync.');
  // Set up periodic sync for Safari
  if ('periodicSync' in self.registration) {
    self.registration.periodicSync.register('my-periodic-sync', {
      // Set the minimum delay to 1 minute
      minDelay: 1 * 60 * 1000, // 1 minute in milliseconds
      // Background sync event handler
      onsync: async (event) => {
        try {
          // Retrieve the background message payload
          const payload = await messaging.onBackgroundMessage();
          // Show notification during periodic sync
          await showNotificationDuringSync(payload);
        } catch (error) {
          console.error('Error handling background message during sync:', error);
        }
      },
    });
  }
} else {
  console.log('Not running Safari, periodic sync not required....');
}
```

However, this does not work either. I am wondering if I should instead implement APNS as this link [here](https://developer.apple.com/notifications/safari-push-notifications/) says the following:

> Use the Apple Push Notifications Service to send notifications to your website users, right on their Mac desktop — even when Safari isn’t running. Safari Push Notifications work just like push notifications for apps. They display your website icon and notification text, which users can click to go right to your website.

Has anyone successfully implemented background notifications on Safari with firebase messaging? Should I instead be using Apple Push Notification Service or are background notifications in Safari impossible altogether?

A nudge in the right direction would be appreciated!